# Run same liquibase migration on different schemas

Tags: java, database, maven, database-migration, liquibase

I've written a `Maven` project with my DB entity classes and a `Liquibase` schema. The idea is to be able to run a liquibase `changelog` and generate the schema that was there defined. This part works fine, but only for a **single** **schema**. I want to be able to give `Liquibase` another `schemaName` as a parameter, so that it runs the **update** on that schema, received as a parameter.

I know how I can give Liquibase external `schemaName`:

```
<createTable tableName="client" schemaName="${schemaName}">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
```

And compile agains that schema:

```
mvn compile liquibase:update -DschemaName=my-schema
```

The problem is with this that it expects the same `schemaName` that was defined in `liquibase.properties` file, so this is not really parametrized. I can give it a `schemaName` as a property, but **also need to change in the properties file** to match with the command line argument.

**liquibase.properties**

```
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
# currentSchema needs to be changed every time --> problem
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/my-db?currentSchema=my-schema
username: postgres
password: root
```

Otherwise it doesn't create the **databasechangelog** and **databasechangeloglock** to the schema given as a parameter, thus losing track of the changes in that schema.

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- use Liquibase plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>db/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I want to:

1. either **only** give it `schemaName` as command line argument
2. or **only** set it up on some `properties file`

For sure **not** both places. How would this be done?